# An unexpected NULL value was returned for column "[MSDASQL] - OPENQUERY en SQL

Tags: tsql, transact-sql, db2

actualmente tengo el siguiente script, el cual lo estoy corriendo en DB2, el cual basicamente es un estado de cuenta de una cuenta

```
 SELECT
  CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(TR.TRAVDD,'-'),TR.TRAVDM),'-'),TR.TRAVDY) AS "FECHA"
 ,DATE(TR.TRAVDY || '-' || TR.TRAVDM || '-' || TR.TRAVDD) AS FECHA2
 ,CASE
      WHEN TR.TRADCC = 0 THEN TR.TRAAMT
      ELSE '' END AS "RETIRO"
 ,CASE
      WHEN TR.TRADCC = 5 THEN TR.TRAAMT
      ELSE '' END AS "DEPOSITO"
 
 FROM TRANSACTION TR
 WHERE TR.TRAACC = '1043101370506'
```

En DB2 me genera el siguiente resultado con valores Nulos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
2-3-2023    2023-03-02  4.00          ++++++++++++
2-3-2023    2023-03-02  1100.00       ++++++++++++
31-3-2023   2023-03-31  ++++++++++++    14.38
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  10000.00      ++++++++++++
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  20.00         ++++++++++++
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  ++++++++++++    100000.00
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  200.00        ++++++++++++
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  2.00          ++++++++++++
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  ++++++++++++    13680.00
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  80000.00      ++++++++++++
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  150.00        ++++++++++++
1-4-2023    2023-04-01  160.00        ++++++++++++
3-4-2023    2023-04-03  ++++++++++++    1934.62
3-4-2023    2023-04-03  1209.14       ++++++++++++
3-4-2023    2023-04-03  6.05          ++++++++++++
3-4-2023    2023-04-03  1209.14       ++++++++++++
3-4-2023    2023-04-03  6.05          ++++++++++++
5-4-2023    2023-04-05  ++++++++++++    1000.00
6-4-2023    2023-04-06  20000.00      ++++++++++++
6-4-2023    2023-04-06  40.00         ++++++++++++
```

los que salen con + en teoria son los valores nulos, la cosa es que en SQL cuando quiero realizar esta consulta mediante OpenQuery me genera el siguiente error

Comparto Script y captura de error

```
DECLARE @Cuenta NVARCHAR(30) = '1043101370506'
DECLARE @TSQL2 VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @TSQL2 = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(IBSREPORT,''
SELECT 
,DATE(TR.TRAVDY || ''''-'''' || TR.TRAVDM || ''''-'''' || TR.TRAVDD) AS "FECHA
,CASE
     WHEN TR.TRADCC = 0 THEN TR.TRAAMT
     ELSE '''' '''' END AS "RETIRO"
FROM TRANSACTION TR
WHERE TR.TRAACC = '''''+@Cuenta+'''''
'')'

EXEC(@TSQL2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo solucionar ese error?

Comment: El problema seguramente no es esta consulta sin el insert que haces de los datos, el error lo dice, se está esperando que la columna RETIRO no sea NULL, y estás devolviendo esto, tal vez puedas reemplazar este valor por un 0.